# Does 2 Kings 13:21 foreshadow the event in Matthew 27:52?

Tags: matthew, 2-kings

2 Kings 13:

> 20 And Elisha died and was buried.
>
> Now the Moabite raiders used to come into the land every spring. 21Once, as the Israelites were burying a man, suddenly they saw a band of raiders, so they threw the man’s body into Elisha’s tomb. And as soon as his body touched the bones of Elisha, the man was revived and stood up on his feet.

Matthew 27:

> 50 And when Jesus had cried out again in a loud voice, he gave up his spirit.
>
> 51At that moment the curtain of the temple was torn in two from top to bottom. The earth shook, the rocks split 52and the tombs broke open. The bodies of many holy people who had died were raised to life. 53They came out of the tombs after Jesus’ resurrection and e went into the holy city and appeared to many people.

Does 2 Kings 13:21 foreshadow the event in Matthew 27:52? How do they compare?

Answer (score 1):

In the technical jargon of theology (both ancient and modern) the story in 2 Kings 13 is seen as a "Type" of Christ.  Almost every story in the OT can be viewed through this lens.  For example, Joseph was a "Type" of Christ -

- both are rejected by their own people
- both became servants
- both are betrayed for silver
- both are falsely accused and face false witnesses
- both attain stations at the "right hand" of the respective thrones (Joseph at Pharaoh's throne and Christ at the throne of God)
- Joseph was 30 years old when he stood before Pharaoh, and Jesus was about the same age according to the bible when he began his ministry
- Both became a savior to their people by going to Egypt; Joseph as a lad of 17 and Jesus as a baby (Matt 2:15)

Similarly, Rom 5 discusses Adam as a Type of Christ:

- Adam was the first born of the living (Gen 2:7-20) made in the image of God, and given dominion over creatures and the earth (Gen 1:26). Jesus was the first born of the dead (meaning resurrected) and the very likeness of the invisible God (Col 1:15), given dominion over 'kings of the earth' (Rev 1:4-5) indeed authority over all creation (Matt 28:18)
- Adam was without bride but given one (Gen 2:18-21); Jesus was without bride but given one (John 3:29)
- Adam's bride came from Adam (Gen 2:23) requiring his side be pierced (Gen 2:21), and the two became one (Gen 2:24) (Matt 19:6); Jesus’ bride came from Jesus (Matt 16:19; 18:18; John 14:20) requiring his side be pierced (John 19:34), and the two became one (John 17:21)
- Before Adam, the Spirit hovered over the waters (Gen 1:2); Before Jesus, the Spirit hovered over Mary’s womb (Luke 1:35) and was present over the water at Jesus’ baptism (Matt 3:11, 16)
- Adam was cursed with thorns (Gen 3:18); Jesus was mocked with a crown of thorns (Mark 5:17)

... and so forth.  Almost every story in the Bible has been eulogized in this was and is consistent with Jesus' own words in Luke 24:27 -

> And beginning with Moses and all the Prophets, He explained to them
> what was written in all the Scriptures about Himself.

... or again in John 5:39 -

> You diligently search the Scriptures because you think to have eternal
> life in them, and these are they bearing witness concerning Me;

Answer (score 0):

Elisha was a type of Christ.

https://www.ligonier.org/learn/articles/meditating-scripture/

Ligonier is a well-respected Christian organization founded by R C Sproul.

> Both are designated by a prophet, whom the general populace recognized as a true prophet. Both receive the Spirit on the other side of the Jordan (2 Kings 2:7-15; John 1:28); are surrounded by more disciples than their predecessors; are itinerant miracle workers; give life in a land of death; cleanse lepers (2 Kings 5; Mark 1:40-45); heal the sick (2 Kings 4:34-35; Mark 8:22-25); defy gravity (2 Kings 6:6; Matt. 14:22-33); reverse death by raising dead sons and restoring them to their mothers (2 Kings 4: 1-7; Luke 7:11-17); help widows in desperate
> circumstances; are kinsman redeemers to save from slavery (2 Kings 4:1-7; Luke 4:19); feed the hungry (2 Kings 4:1-7; Mark 8:1-12); minister to the Gentiles (2 Kings 5:1-16); prepare (2 Kings 6:20-23) and sit at table with sinners (Luke 5:29); lead captives (2 Kings 6:18-20; Eph, 4:7-8); have a covetous disciple (Gehazi and Judas); **end their lives in a life-giving tomb from which people flee** (2 Kings 13:20-21; Mark 16:1-8).

Does 2 Kings 13:21 foreshadow the event in Matthew 27:52?

Yes, in fact, it is a type.